# Getting NaN with pointDistance when I don't think I should be

Tags: r, distance, spatial, raster, euclidean-distance

I am unsure why, but pointDistance from the R raster package was working swimmingly until it encountered the following

```
library(raster)
pointDistance(c(34.3, -116.2), c(35.3, -109.5), lonlat = T)
```

for which it returns NaN. I can't even begin to fathom why this would be the case.  Any thoughts?

Comment: What language are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

The order should be *longitude*/*latitude*, you have it reversed.

```
library(raster)
pointDistance(c(-116.2, 34.3), c(-109.5, 35.3), lonlat = TRUE)
[1] 622940
```